# How do I use an imagestream from another namespace in openshift?

Tags: openshift

I have been breaking my head over the following:

I have a set of buildconfigs that build images and create imagestreams for it in the "openshift" namespace. This gives me for example the netclient-userspace imagestream.

```
krist@MacBook-Pro netmaker % oc get is netclient-userspace
NAME                  IMAGE REPOSITORY                                                                 TAGS     UPDATED
netclient-userspace   image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/openshift/netclient-userspace   latest   About an hour ago
```

What I have however not been able to figure out is how to use this imagestream in a deployment in a different namespace.

Take for example this:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: netclient-test
  namespace: "kvb-netclient-test"
spec:
  containers:
    - name: netclient
      image: netclient-userspace:latest
```

When I deploy this I get errors...

```
Failed to pull image "netclient-userspace:latest": rpc error: code =
Unknown desc = reading manifest latest in
docker.io/library/netclient-userspace: errors: denied: requested
access to the resource is denied unauthorized: authentication required
```

So openshift goest and looks for the image on dockerhub. It shouldn't. How do I tell openshift to use the imagestream here?

Comment: _Usually_, this is referenced by `ImageStreamTag` on the `DeploymentConfig`. But, if you're using a `Pod` directly, you'll need to look at `oc set image-lookup`. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.11/openshift_images/using-imagestreams-with-kube-resources.html However, I'm not sure that this solves your "other namespace" use case

Comment: I use DeploymmentConfig most of the time, but in this case I just quickly wanted to test the container.

Comment: You need to create a service account and allow the service account to access an imagestream in different namespace. I believe that you can deploy your deploymentconfig/deployment with the service account using the imagestream.

Comment: and you will need to add RoleBinding in the "provider namespace" to grant the role "system:image-puller" to the service accounts of the "beneficiary namespace"

Answer (score 0):

When using an ImageStreamTag for a Deployment image source, you need to use the [`image.openshift.io/triggers` annotation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.10/openshift_images/triggering-updates-on-imagestream-changes.html). It instructs OpenShift to replace the `image:` attribute in a Deployment with the value of an ImageStreamTag (and to redeploy it when the ImageStreamTag changes in the future).

Importantly, note the annotation and the `image: ' '` with the explicit space character in the yaml string.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    image.openshift.io/triggers: '[{"from":{"kind":"ImageStreamTag","name":"content-netclient-userspace:latest","namespace":"openshift"},"fieldPath":"spec.template.spec.containers[?(@.name==\"netclient\")].image"}]'
  name: netclient-test
  namespace: "kvb-netclient-test"
spec:
  ...
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - ...
        image: ' '
        name: netclient
...
```

I will also mention that, in order to pull images from different namespaces, it may be required to authorize the Deployment's service account to do so: [OpenShift Docs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.10/openshift_images/managing_images/using-image-pull-secrets.html#images-allow-pods-to-reference-images-across-projects_using-image-pull-secrets).